# Is there any method to convert a quantization aware pytorch model to .tflite?

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow-lite, yolov4, quantization-aware-training, static-quantization

I have trained yolov4-tiny on pytorch with quantization aware training. My model layers look like

```
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight
module_list.0.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.scale
module_list.0.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.zero_point
module_list.0.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.range_tracker.min_val
module_list.0.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.range_tracker.max_val
module_list.0.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.range_tracker.first_a
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight_quantizer.scale
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight_quantizer.zero_point
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight_quantizer.range_tracker.min_val
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight_quantizer.range_tracker.max_val
module_list.0.Conv2d.weight_quantizer.range_tracker.first_w
module_list.0.BatchNorm2d.weight
module_list.0.BatchNorm2d.bias
module_list.0.BatchNorm2d.running_mean
module_list.0.BatchNorm2d.running_var
module_list.0.BatchNorm2d.num_batches_tracked
module_list.1.Conv2d.weight
module_list.1.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.scale
module_list.1.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.zero_point
module_list.1.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.range_tracker.min_val
module_list.1.Conv2d.activation_quantizer.range_tracker.max_val 
...
```

I tried some methods to convert it to tflite, but I am getting error as
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Darknet:
Missing key(s) in state_dict:

I think the reason is that quantization aware training added some new layers, hence tflite conversion is giving error messages.

Any idea how to solve this?